# Google Drive Proxy Authentication

Tags: proxy, google-drive-api

How we can add or configure the proxy authentication for Google Drive?

Currently, Google Drive does not support this feature, so how can we successfully connect Google Drive to the internet using proxy authentication?

I mean, is there any way to edit a file or edit registry so that Google Drive can be connected using proxy authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [blog](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/120790.aspx), Google Drive can work though a proxy server (such as the Sophos UTM, or Sophos Web Appliance), but Google does not support authentication for connections to their addresses.  To allow Google Drive to work though your proxy, you must bypass authentication for the addresses contained in this [Google article](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2589954). You may also check this [Google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/yeyWx00XR1k) about proxy authentication.